# Change background color on HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using CorinTech's "Flies Thru the Air" software to monitor some wireless temperature data loggers. The data chart package they use is by HighCharts.
I would like to be able to change the background color of the chart from BLACK to WHITE as sometimes I have to print the chart in color and all of the black makes the paper soggy AND burns through ink needlessly.
Is there a way to change this ?
THanks, Steve

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. See [`backgroundColor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.backgroundColor).

```
...
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
    },
...
```

You would need access to the code page that is rendering the charts to modify the value this software is using. By default the color is white but this software has created a theme of some sort. So, to make it white you just delete the `backgroundColor` property.